# FormAssembly Date and Time from Military/24 hour to Standard/12 hour format

Tags: forms, date, datetime, time, salesforce

I am utilizing FormAssembly to prefill forms with data from our Salesforce database. In Salesforce we have a field that shows date and time together as:

Event Start Date/Time (SALESFORCE): 11/30/2023 5:00 PM

But when it comes over to the form it shows up as:
Event Start Date (FORMASSEMBLY): 11/30/2023 17:00:00

I have some knowledge about coding, but it is very basic information and it's been years since I have used it. So I am having issues with converting it so that the Event Start Date on FormAssembly will show up as 11/30/2023 5:00 PM.

I can set certain fields on the form as variables and they provide a section to enter in custom code (html, css, or javascript). I have included screenshots of where I can assign a variable name on a field in the form, where I can add calculations to a field, and the place where I can insert the custom code. I also include an image of the field on the form itself. I can also create other fields to make them hidden so that we can use the prefilled text box as the variable. If someone can help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

[FormAssembly Custom Code Field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jB1Lk.png)

[FormAssembly Add Calculated Field or assign variable name to field on form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNoDp.png)

[FormAssembly Form showing Event Start Date field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iir3R.png)

I have tried entering CSS code, assigning the Event Start Date as a variable and having the data fall into a second field. But I am missing something because it continues to not work. And most items I find are about doing this on websites and not sure how to reflect those instructions onto FormAssembly.